# Iterating through table rows (tr) and selecting rows without a specific class in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I am trying to do is, to be able to select rows which do not have a specific class name, and push them into a new array. I know that there is `:not() Selector` and `.not() method` to help me with this.

But the big problem is that I can't use `:not() Selector` with `$(this)` and tried using `.not() method` but couldn't get anywhere.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#getRows').on('click', function() {
    var temp = new Array();
    $('#tbl tr').each(function(){
      var clsFree = $(this).not(document.getElementsByClassName("testCls"));
      temp.push(clsFree);
    });
    console.log(temp.length);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="getRows">Get rows without class</button>
<table id="tbl">
  <tr class="testCls"><td>Test1</td></tr>
  <tr class="testCls"><td>Test2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Test3</td></tr>
  <tr class="testCls"><td>Test4</td></tr>
  <tr class="testCls"><td>Test5</td></tr>
  <tr class="testCls"><td>Test6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Test7</td></tr>
  <tr class="testCls"><td>Test8</td></tr>
  <tr class="testCls"><td>Test9</td></tr>
</table>
```

> Please note that the main goal here is to find rows that don't have a class name with `testCls` and push them into a new array. Any other method is also appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `:not()` as part of the selector in `.each` iterator to iterate over only with the selected rows in the selector:

`$('#tbl tr:not(.testCls)').each(function(){`

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#getRows').on('click', function() {
    var temp = new Array();
    $('#tbl tr:not(.testCls)').each(function(){
      var clsFree = this;
      temp.push(clsFree);
    });
    console.log(temp.length);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="getRows">Get rows without class</button>
<table id="tbl">
  <tr class="testCls"><td>Test1</td></tr>
  <tr class="testCls"><td>Test2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Test3</td></tr>
  <tr class="testCls"><td>Test4</td></tr>
  <tr class="testCls"><td>Test5</td></tr>
  <tr class="testCls"><td>Test6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Test7</td></tr>
  <tr class="testCls"><td>Test8</td></tr>
  <tr class="testCls"><td>Test9</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

two things:

- this is the syntax for the .not: `$(this).not('.testCls');`
- clsFree is going to be a jQuery, and jQuerys still exist even if there are no elements in them. You have to check the length to see if there are any elements.

also as an aside, you might end up being happier with something like this:
`$('#tbl tr:not(.testCls)').each...`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#getRows').on('click', function() {
        var temp = new Array();
        $('#tbl tr').each(function() {
            clsFree = $(this).not('.testCls');
            if (clsFree.length > 0)
                temp.push(clsFree);
        });
        console.log(temp.length);
    });

    console.log('other method', $('#tbl tr:not(.testCls)').length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <button id="getRows">Get rows without class</button>
 <table id="tbl">
  <tr class="testCls"><td>Test1</td></tr>
  <tr class="testCls"><td>Test2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Test3</td></tr>
  <tr class="testCls"><td>Test4</td></tr>
  <tr class="testCls"><td>Test5</td></tr>
  <tr class="testCls"><td>Test6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Test7</td></tr>
  <tr class="testCls"><td>Test8</td></tr>
  <tr class="testCls"<td>Test9</tr></tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: your information saying _clsFree is going to be a jQuery, and jQuerys still exist_ was very helpful. And of course your solution is correct. Thanks.